# Why is my programme of openpyxl not working as it should?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to make a programme which works like a test correcter. It opens a excel workbook in which there must be two sheets, in one of them the names and the chosen letter and in the other one the corrected exam. The programme should create a new sheet(which I did) and write the marks of each one. I made an other programme which changes a number value to that number in the alphabet (I discovered too late that sheet(row=1, column=1) = 'hi' was possible) The problem I have is that, when it passes to the sheet named correction the values it doesn't work as expected. Here's my codes and the excel sheets.

This is the worksheet with the responses of each person

[image]

This one is the one with the correct answers

[image]

This is the one with the output of my programme

[image]

This is the one with the output I'd like to have:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from ABCDE import ABCD

workbook = 'CETT.xlsx'
rsp = load_workbook(workbook, data_only=True)
rspage = rsp[input('Name of the responses sheet: ')]
copage = rsp[input('Name of the correction sheet: ')]
n_ques = int(input('Number of questions: '))
n_answ = rspage.max_row - 1

correct = []
responses = []
correction = []

def cct():
    
    for i in range(n_ques):
        
        cell = ABCD(i + 1) + '2'
        
        correct.append(copage[cell].value)

a = []

def rrp():
        
    global a
    
    for i in range(n_answ):
        
        for j in range(n_ques + 1):
            
            c = ABCD(j + 1)
            a.append(rspage[c + str(i + 2)].value)
            
        responses.append(a)
        a = []
        
def crt():
    
    crpage = rsp.create_sheet('correction')
    
    for i in range(n_answ):
        
        b = []
        b.append(responses[i][0])
        crpage[ABCD(i+n_answ) + str(1)] = responses[i][0]
        
        for j in range(n_ques):
            
            if responses[i][j+1] == correct[j]:
                
                b.append(responses[i][j+1])
                crpage[ABCD(j+2) + str(i+1)] = responses[i][j+1]
                
            else:
                
                b.append('w: ' + str(responses[i][j+1]) + ' c: ' + str(correct[j]))
                crpage[ABCD(j+2) + str(i+1)] = 'w: ' + str(responses[i][j+1]) + ' c: ' + str(correct[j])
        
        correction.append(b)
        
    rsp.save('CETT.xlsx')
         
cct()
rrp()
crt()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line assigning the names is wrong:

```
        crpage[ABCD(i+n_answ) + str(1)] = responses[i][0]
```

You want that always in column A, in the row indexed by answer.

```
        crpage['A'+str(i+1)] = responses[i][0]
```

You can eliminate almost all of your globals by using functions properly:

```
def ABCD(k):
    return chr(64+k)
def Cell(c,r):
    return ABCD(c)+str(r)

def cct():
    correct = []
    for i in range(n_ques):
        cell = Cell(i+1, 2)
        correct.append(copage[cell].value)
    return correct


def rrp():
    responses = []
    for i in range(n_answ):
        a = []
        for j in range(n_ques + 1):
            c = ABCD(j + 1)
            a.append(rspage[c + str(i + 2)].value)
        responses.append(a)
    return responses
        
def crt(correct, responses):
    
    crpage = rsp.create_sheet('correction')
    
    for i in range(n_answ):
        crpage['A'+str(i+1)] = responses[i][0]
        
        for j in range(n_ques):
            response = responses[i][j+1]
            if response != correct[j]:
                response = 'w: ' + response + ' c: ' + str(correct[j])

            crpage[Cell(j+2,i+1)] = response
        
    rsp.save('CETT.xlsx')
         
correct = cct()
responses = rrp()
crt(correct, responses)
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it shorter?

Comment: Why?  The number of  lines is irrelevant.  pandas would make the input simpler, but the total processing wouldn't change that much.

Comment: There is no reason, I just wanted to know